# TSlint remove global rules

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am coding an Angular project, using VSCode, while using the extension TSlint. My problem is that TSlint is applying some rules that are just tedious to me. I would like to disable some of the rules in my TSlint extension. How can I do this?

I know you can change the rules by editing the tslint.json in your Angular project. But how can I affect my global TSlintfor every project?

Comment: are you sure you have any global tslint related to all your projects. As far as I understand tslint.json is per project, not?

Look, here is the quote from WebStorm settings hint: "When linting a TypeScript file, TSLint looks for tslint.json or tslint.yaml starting from the file's folder and then moving up to the filesystem root or in the user's home directory"

Comment: Oh ok, might be. I am not really sure hey.